# ZF2: How can i use brackets to group in mysql where in DB\SQL?

Tags: zend-framework2

I have the following code:

```
$select = new Select();
$select->from($this->table);
$select->columns(array('id', 'refNumberOrder', 'dateOrder', 'kontragent', 'airOperator', 'aircraft', 'status'));

...

if ($object->customer != '') {
    $select->where->like('library_kontragent.short_name', $object->customer . '%');
}

if ($object->airOperator != '') {
    $select->where->like('library_air_operator.short_name', $object->airOperator . '%');
}

if ($object->aircraft != '') {
    $select->where->like('library_aircraft_type.name', $object->aircraft . '%');
}

$select->order('dateOrder ' . Select::ORDER_DESCENDING);
//\Zend\Debug\Debug::dump($select->getSqlString());

$resultSet = $this->selectWith($select);
$resultSet->buffer();
```

This makes the next line:

```
// MySQL result
WHERE "library_kontragent"."short_name" LIKE 'test%' 
    AND "library_air_operator"."short_name" LIKE 'test%' 
    AND "library_aircraft_type"."name" LIKE 'test%' 
ORDER BY "dateOrder" DESC"
```

How I can get next a string?

```
// MySQL result
WHERE ("library_kontragent"."short_name" LIKE 'test%' OR "library_kontragent"."long_name" LIKE 'test%') 
    AND "library_air_operator"."short_name" LIKE 'test%' 
    AND "library_aircraft_type"."name" LIKE 'test%' 
ORDER BY "dateOrder" DESC"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [this example](https://github.com/ralphschindler/Zend_Db-Examples/blob/master/example-13.php#L10) by Ralph Schindler. There's a `NEST` and `UNNEST` "operator" within `Zend\Db\Sql\Where`